# How can I do Monster Hunter Tri Online?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-tri

I'm playing Monster Hunter 3 Tri and whenever I try to go to the city there's an error.

How can I do Monster Hunter Tri Online?

Comment: Can you try and give some additional information, such as the wording of the error message and details of your internet connection. The more information you can provide the more likely you will get useful answers.

Comment: @Colin I think it's enough info

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 11):

You can't.  The Tri servers were [shut down](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2013/04/the_monster_hunter_tri_servers_will_be_shutdown_today) on April 13, 2013.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The Wii's and DS' servers were shut down, so you can no longer play Wii or DS games online.

Comment: Monster Hunter 3G/U on the DS did NOT have online options.  The only way you can play online is to connect to a WiiU, then the WiiU goes online with all the DS connected locally.  It was only 4G/U that gave DS itself the online capabilities.

Comment: That's lovely, I never said otherwise.

Comment: So if the DS didn't have online available, what servers got shutdown?

Comment: @Nelson The DS's servers, used for a variety of games that are not 3U.